# Exception: Malformed HTML content: </div> Error

Tags: html, google-apps-script, html-email, template-engine

Im trying to get my Google spreadsheet to send an email with the data from the sheet thats also html formatted. Whenever i try to run it i get I keep getting the following error...

> Error Exception: Malformed HTML content: 
> .
> eval
> eval
> myFunction  @ waiverClaim.gs:37

and i cant find the issue. I assume the issue is with line 37 "const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();" but i dont know whats wrong, hopefully someone here can help!

Here is the script im running

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Football");

  const h1 = ws.getRange("A1").getValue();
  const subheader = ws.getRange("A4:F4").getValues();
  const priority = subheader[0][0];
  const player = subheader[0][1];
  const transaction = subheader[0][2];
  const bid = subheader[0][3];
  const years = subheader[0][4]; 
  const dropped = subheader[0][5];

  const lr =  ws.getLastRow();

  const tableRangeValues = ws.getRange(5,1,lr-5,6).getValues();

  const totalLine = ws.getRange(lr,3,1,6).getValues();
  const totalText = totalLine[0][0];
  const totalSum = totalLine[0][1];

const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");

htmlTemplate.h1 = h1;
htmlTemplate.subheader = subheader;
htmlTemplate.priority = priority;
htmlTemplate.player = player;
htmlTemplate.transaction = transaction;
htmlTemplate.bid = bid;
htmlTemplate.years = years;
htmlTemplate.dropped = dropped;
htmlTemplate.totalText = totalText;
htmlTemplate.totalSum = totalSum;
htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues = tableRangeValues;


const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

console.log(htmlForEmail);

GmailApp.sendEmail(
  "me@gmail.com",
  "Waiver Claim Submission",
  "Tom Brady $45 1 year",
  { htmlBody: htmlForEmail }
);

}
```

and the corresponding html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
       </head>
        <body>
             <div>

                <div>
                      <h1><?= h1 ?></h1>
                </div>
                      
                <div> 
                      <div <?= subheader ?></div>
                </div>

              </div> 

        <table>
              <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                            <th><?= priority ?></th>
                            <th><?= player ?></th>
                            <th><?= transaction ?></th>
                            <th><?= bid ?></th>
                            <th><?= years ?></th>
                            <th><?= dropped ?></th>
                        </tr>  
                
               </thead>
       
               <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td>Col D1</td>
                            <td>Col D2</td>
                            <td>Col D3</td>
                            <td>Col D4</td>
                            <td>Col D5</td>
                            <td>Col D6</td>
                        </tr>  
              </tbody>


                <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><?= totalText ?></td>
                            <td><?= totalSum ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>     
                        </tr> 
                </tfoot>
          </table>    
     </body>
</html>
```

If i need to offer any more information on the situation i would be glad to.

Comment: Well at a minimum the html is incomplete but I think the scriptlets are okay.  Add the rest of the html to make it a complete html page. Try simplifying it until it works and then slowly add everything back until it stops working again.

Comment: This `const tableRangeValues = ws.getRange(5,1,lr-5,6).getValues();'  should be `const tableRangeValues = ws.getRange(5,1,lr-4,6).getValues();`

Comment: Sorry, i didnt realize the top of the HTML got cut off. I updated the post to reflect the whole code. Im still getting that error what i change the const tableRangeValues though.

Comment: You can make it easier to find such issues yourself by using a validator - for example, here is an [online HTML validator](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html). I pasted your HTML into that tool and the 5th report item shows the problem. Given you are using pre-processor tags also, such as `<?= dropped ?>`, you can make your HTML less "noisy" by removing all of those, carefully... (you can use a regex for that, or do it by hand).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `>` in `<div <?= subheader ?></div>`.

Try with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
       </head>
        <body>
             <div>

                <div>
                      <h1><?= h1 ?></h1>
                </div>
                      
                <div> 
                      <div> <?= subheader ?></div>
                </div>

              </div> 

        <table>
              <thead> 
                        <tr> 
                            <th><?= priority ?></th>
                            <th><?= player ?></th>
                            <th><?= transaction ?></th>
                            <th><?= bid ?></th>
                            <th><?= years ?></th>
                            <th><?= dropped ?></th>
                        </tr>  
                
               </thead>
       
               <tbody> 
                        <tr> 
                            <td>Col D1</td>
                            <td>Col D2</td>
                            <td>Col D3</td>
                            <td>Col D4</td>
                            <td>Col D5</td>
                            <td>Col D6</td>
                        </tr>  
              </tbody>


                <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><?= totalText ?></td>
                            <td><?= totalSum ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>     
                        </tr> 
                </tfoot>
          </table>    
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good catch I didn't see that. I looked right at that line too.  I could tell there was something wrong from the color.